# How to modify the default "Index of" page in OpenBSD 5.3 httpd

Tags: openbsd, openbsd-httpd

Using the old apache:

```
# grep -i httpd /etc/rc.conf 
httpd_flags="-DSSL"
# grep -i nginx /etc/rc.conf 
nginx_flags=NO
#
```

How can I modify the custom "Index of" page?

[image]

**Question**: The only problem with the default "Index of" page is that the "NAME" column has way too short width. How can I increase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set options in your `.htaccess` file. For example, I have the following set for a directory that contains long file names:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=*
</IfModule>
```

with the `NameWidthe=*` option being the one you're interested in. Check out [this article](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) for all sorts of tips on `.htaccess` customization.

Comment: Also, [Apache httpd docs on the subject](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz - right, those too :)